# Minimize a sympy expression

Tags: scipy, sympy, minimize

I have a sympy expression that depends on a variable x, and I want to find the value x for which the expression is minimized. This is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from scipy.optimize import minimize as scipy_min

x = Symbol('x')
p = Symbol('p')
 
f = exp(-(x-p)**2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)

func = lambdify([x,p], f)
def func_np(x):
    return func(x,2.2)

res = scipy_min(func_np, x, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)
```

However I am getting the error: `can't convert expression to float`. Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: That's not how minimize works. Scipy is a numeric package. You can use sympy for an analytical solution or scipy for a numeric one, but not both

Comment: @MadPhysicist but I didn't find a way to minimize a sympy expression directly

Comment: Set the partial derivatives to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument in `minimize` is an initial guess, a number, not a variable. You are trying to pass a `sympy.Symbol`, which is definitely not a number. It is ok to minimize lambdified function, however, be aware that lambdify is (relatively) slow, so it could be better to `print(expression)` and create a `def` manually.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from scipy.optimize import minimize as scipy_min

x = Symbol('x')
p = Symbol('p')
 
f = exp(-(x-p)**2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)

func = lambdify([x,p], f)
def func_np(x):
    return func(x,2.2)

res = scipy_min(func_np, 1.0, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)
print(res.x)
```

yields `-37.3`. However, it is not the solution, because this particular function goes towards 0 when x goes towards ±∞.